# Сокет на PHP. Простой пример

Tags: php, websocket

Всем привет. Можете показать простой робочей сокет на пхп. Простой сокет выводящий статичную строку без приема данных. Думаю не затруднит. 
И еще один вопрос. Сокет работает если подключаешься только по нужному порту (например example.com:8000) или при любом подключении. В этом всем новичек.

Answer (score 1):

Простой пример, который просто слушает и отвечает **Hi! its work!** при обращении

```
    <?php

    $socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:8000", $errorNumber, $errorDescription);

    if (!$socket) {
        die("$errorDescription ($errorNumber)\n");
    }

    while ($connect = stream_socket_accept($socket, -1)) {
        fwrite($connect, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nHi! its work!\n\n");
        fclose($connect);
    }

    fclose($socket);
```

Comment: А как обратиться к этому слушателю?